# If I leave the 'for' statement, the data will disappear

Tags: python-3.x

I did for loop. but The data in for loop is valid. but the data disappear except a few. I don't know why it is. I used two for loop(not same each other). and The two is same. I work in jupyter note. but I don't know this is the reason.

In the first for loop. I thought It just my mistake. so I save the file as CSV in the first for loop. but In the second for loop, the problem appear.

```
for i in range(0,191):

    coord_i = np.load(''+st[i].id+'.npy')
    print(coord_i)   # It is valid. I can see all coord_i. because It is in this for loop

print(coord_1)   # error : name 'coord_1' is not defined. beacuse It is not in above for loop
```

I don't know what I miss. Please help me.

Comment: You're printing `coord_1`, it isn't declared, you probably mean `coord_i`. And there's only one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in a comment by MrGeek, coord_1 is not defined, coord_i is the only thing defined.
Secondly,if you want to print it after with

```
print(coord_i)
```

command, that will just show you last one, number 190 coord_i, as every time you reset this variable. If you want to keep all of them and print afterwards ill recommend you to do following adjustments:

```
list_coord=[]
for i in range(0,191):

    coord_i = np.load(''+st[i].id+'.npy')
    list_coord.append(coord_i)
    print(coord_i)   
print(list_coord)
```

So u can have all your data stored

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works well!!
Should I ask you another code?

for i in range(0,192):

    for j in range(0,154):

        st[i].stats["coordinates"]={}

        if cola[j,0]==''+st[i].stats.station+'':

            st[i].stats["coordinates"]["latitude"] = cola[j,1]

            st[i].stats["coordinates"]["longitude"] = colo[j,2]

This is my first for loop. It has same problem(the data will disappear out for loop)
It is funny, Out for loop, the coordinate dictionary is there, but other latitude and longitude will disappear.

Comment: you could fix this by adding this line st[i].stats["coordinates"]={}
before all the loops, then it will not dissapear